# HTMLDocument support of span inside span

Tags: java, html, dom

I'm trying to insert this text in my HTMLDocument :

```
<html><span class='stuff' id='X'><span id='Y'>content</span></span></html>
```

using this code :

```
String test = "<html><span class='stuff' id='X'><span id='Y'>content</span></span></html>";
editorKit.read(new StringReader(test), htmlDocument, 0);
```

I expect to read this from the document :

```
<html><head></head><body><span class='stuff' id='X'><span id='Y'>content</span></span></body></html>
```

But I read this instead :

```
<html><head></head><body><span id="Y">content</span></body></html>
```

The outer span disappeared (unfortunately it was the most important for me).

I guess this is happening because Java discovers 2 Span nodes with the same start position and end position and so fusion them. But why doesn't HTMLDocument just keep intact the html we're giving him ?!!! Whatever, I really need to have 2 ids imbricated like that. I could use < div style='display:inline' > instead but it's not supported (only HTML 3.2 is)...

Any solution I could try ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please don't use swear words (even relatively mild ones like the one you used) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That behavior of `EditorKit` and/or `HTMLDocument` seems very, very wrong. But you knew that. :-)

Comment: *"But I read this instead"* Please show us the code where you're doing that, it could be on that end of things.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder
Thank you for your intervention.
I'm sure the problem doesn't come from the lecture because I checked like this :
- setting the htmlContent (using HTMLEditorKit.read, or setText)
- looking for the node : htmlDoc.getElement("X") -> not found
- looking for the node : htmlDoc.getElement("Y") -> found
- checking the aspect of the html : HTMLEditorKit.write, or getText

Comment: I wrote 'lecture'. I meant 'reading'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the problem like this :

I was using Jsoup as a parser so I used it to select all the inner spans. Then I copied their content into a Map, to be able to find them back. I removed the inner spans, I set the modified html in the htmlDocument, and finally, i manually find the outer spans in the htmlDocument thanks to their ids and insert the html read from the Map :

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
    Elements elements = doc.select("span span");
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(Element e : elements) {
        Element parent = e.getParent();
        map.put(parent.attr("id"),e.outerhtml());
        parent.html("PENDING");//the node should not be empty otherwise HTMLDocument will think it is free to remove it...
    }
    editorKit.read(new StringReader(doc.html()), htmlDocument, 0);
    javax.swing.text.Element element = htmlDocument.getElement(id);
    int position = element.getStartOffset();
    new HTMLEditorKit().insertHTML(htmlDocument,position,map.get(id),1,0,Tag.SPAN);
```